# Synaptic Package Manager Reload Error

Tags: updates, software-center, update-manager, synaptic

I'm getting this error when I try to reload Synaptic, I installed apps in terminal via ppa's I found on launchpad.net and dep files from other developer sites...

```
Could not download all repository indexes

The repository may no longer be available or could not be contacted because of network problems. If available an older version of the failed index will be used. Otherwise the repository will be ignored. Check your network connection and ensure the repository address in the preferences is correct.

Failed to fetch dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/nanny/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/nanny/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/nanny/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Someone suggested I edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`When I open it up all I see is the normal ubuntu ppa's

Comment: Can I fix the problem by unticking ppa's in Synaptic Package Manager Edit> Software & Updates > Other Software?

Comment: I was adding ppa sudo apt-add-repository ... sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install ... and getting errors because of the keys I think, still not yet fixed. What's easy way to do things http://blog.launchpad.net/ppa/adding-a-ppas-key-to-ubuntu

Comment: Open Synaptic package manager

Answer (score 0):

Open Synaptic package manage

**Settings> Repositories> Other Software**

Remove the PPAs that are causing problems.
In a terminal type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If any other errors appear with PPAs you'll know how to remove them.